# Fixed block inside scrolling div

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

I have a block with text, which scrolls when the text is large enough.  I want to make an  overlay div over this block. I did it like in [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6q5U/).

If I set `position: fixed` to overlay, then it can't be adjusted to its  own size relative to wrapping div. If I set `position: absolute`, the overlay can fit into wrapper, but it can't stay on the  top while scrolling text.

How can I  overcome this? Is it possible without using javascript?

Comment: why are you using overlay div?

Comment: I want to disable content and enable it only after click on overlay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ojItUbIk/5/edit)

[image]

Some thanges in HTML:

```
<div class="pane">
  <div class="pane-content">
     <p>Wet oxidation is a form of hydrothermal...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pane-overlay">Click to hide overlay</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pane {
    width: 600px;
    height:400px;
    position: relative;
}
.pane-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.pane-overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #c2c2c2;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help me, because text block may have any size and values in demo is only for example

Comment: @БорисСердюк **EDITED** this should work. Take a look.

Comment: Perhaps without additional .pane-content doesn't do. @RokoCBuljan, thanks for a good example

Answer (score 0):

You can use background color and opacity to parent div directly.

And use `backgroun: rgba()` format to set bg color and opacity, this allows opacity only to bg color not for the text

```
.pane {
    width: 600px;
    height:400px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(194, 194, 194, 0.6);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iPayutIy/2/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything inside the pane in a div so that this inner div gets the height of the content.

```
<div class="pane">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6q5U/1/)

Comment: will likely have to do so, if there is no way how to create purely scroll-fixed block inside div